# Android flash xml gallery

Tags: android, xml, actionscript-3, flash

I try to develop a simple xml flash gallery in android. it dose not work when i try to preview the image. can someone help me?

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<galleryPackage>

        <image>

            <imgURL>/mnt/sdcard/SketchCraft/MyDrawing 1.png</imgURL>
    </image>


</galleryPackage>
```

i'm not sure how to refer file in the phone memory in xml. and im expecting many errors with my actionscript and xml file here.

this is my actionscript

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var xmlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("XMLcth.xml");
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(xmlRequest);
var imgData:XML;
var imageLoader:Loader;
var rawImage:String;

var imgNum:Number = 0;

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void{
    imgData= new XML(event.target.data);
    rawImage = imgData.image[imgNum].imgURL;
    imageLoader =new Loader();
    imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(rawImage));
    mc_image.addChild(imageLoader);
    }
```

Comment: what are the errors ?

Comment: it not syntax error. it just not preview the image  "MyDrawing 1.png" on the screen. im expecting a logic error.

Comment: is your `mc_image` already added to the stage? Does your Flash have access to files in SD card? Also, instead of `imageLoader =new Loader;`, try `imageLoader =new Loader();`

Comment: i try doing this just like other basic flash xml gallery. but i do not know how to this in android.

Comment: You can try to debug whether `Loader` can access the SD card files first. Try to print out `event.target.data` & value of `imageLoader` after loading the `URLReqeust`.

Comment: i already put mc_image on the stage and change imageLoader =new Loader; to imageLoader =new Loader(); . and yes my flash have SD card. dose my  xml file path correct?

Comment: To know the path is correct or not, load it & trace it.

Comment: i got this type of error -

TypeError: Error #1092: XML parser failure: Unterminated XML declaration.

 at RECOVER_Test1_Scene3_fla::MainTimeline/xmlLoaded()[RECOVER_Test1_Scene3_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:21]
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, your XML is malformed & cannot be read by ActionScript.

Format your XML as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<galleryPackage>
    <image>
        <imgURL><![CDATA[/mnt/sdcard/SketchCraft/MyDrawing 1.png]]></imgURL>
    </image>
</galleryPackage>
```

You missed a `?` in XML declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
```

Comment: updated the answer. I finally noticed you missed a `?` in XML header

Comment: you right i missed that. and now i get this error - Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.

Comment: that's it . The SD card path is either incorrect / inaccessible .

Comment: im sure the location of file is right. /mnt/sdcard/SketchCraft/MyDrawing 1.png. do you think i missed something here. im also double check the file location in the phone.

Comment: do you think this information have to do to something with the file location?
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/228215-working-with-resourses/

Comment: Android permission does not allow you to do so.

Comment: do i need to get Android permission to allow to do that?

Comment: does xml file should be in the phone storage or it be find to put it in some where else?

Comment: is there a other way that i can do to read the image file "MyDrawing 1.png" in XML??

Comment: No, unless you can bypass the permission by Android . No solution .